# ANT <propertyfile> task changes are committed after the execution

Tags: java, ant

I am using a property file in ANT build script. Now, I am modifying some properties in the file based on the user input. The problem is that the changes are not effective during the execution but once the execution completes.

Here is the ANT script:

```
<project name="testProject" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property file="my.properties"/>
    <target name="test" depends="input">
        <echo>${user}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="input">
        <echo>Taking user input</echo>
        <input message="Please enter db-username:" addproperty="db.user"/>

        <propertyfile   file="my.properties">
            <entry  key="user" value="${db.user}"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here is my.properties file:

```
#Fri, 23 May 2014 21:23:43 +0530
#My properties
#Thu, 22 May 2014 19:01:12 +0530
test=1
user=test
```

Here is the output after running:

```
D:\tmp>ant
Buildfile: D:\tmp\build.xml

input:
     [echo] Taking user input
    [input] Please enter db-username:
me
[propertyfile] Updating property file: D:\tmp\my.properties

test:
     [echo] test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

But the file my.properties is update with `user=me`. Please tell me if this is the correct way of doing or any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting scenario, you can do the way how you are doing now. There will no problem but unnecessary complex for maintenance.

if you have different db user names you should pre define in property file instead of overwriting during execution.

```
dev.username="dev1234"(..${db.user})
qa.username="q1234"


prod.username="prodxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, once an Ant property is set, its value is immutable. It cannot change.

Second, once a property is set with `<property file="my.properties"/>`, the property's value cannot change. Even if `my.properties` has changed, further calls to `<property file="my.properties"/>` will not overwrite any existing properties.

Third, the `<echo>` in the `test` target doesn't echo the user's input.

This...

```
<target name="test" depends="input">
    <echo>${user}</echo>
</target>
```

...should be...

```
<target name="test" depends="input">
    <echo>${db.user}</echo>
</target>
```

Finally, the `<propertyfile>` task appears to create a new property in `my.properties`:

```
<propertyfile   file="my.properties">
    <entry  key="username" value="${db.user}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

The above creates a property named `username` in `my.properties`. However, the rest of the script refers to the plain `user` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `username`/`user` was typo which I corrected. But I guess you got the problem.